# How to run `dtrace` at reboot and keep it running to monitor a file on MacOS

Tags: macos, dtrace

I am trying to discover what application is creating a file in /private/tmp.

I've temporarily turned off sip on this Mac.

I created a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo iosnoop -f /private/tmp/AlTest1.err > /private/tmp/iosnoop.txt
```

I created a crontab to run that shell script at reboot:

`$crontab -e`

```
#run at reboot
@reboot /Users/username/Desktop/run_iosnoop.sh
```

Upon restarting I only get the headers for the iosnoop command in my iosnoop.txt file

`UID   PID D    BLOCK   SIZE       COMM PATHNAME`

How can I keep `iosnoop` running during and after reboot to catch the application that is creating this file?

I tried using `@login` instead of `@reboot` but it's not a valid timestamp for cron on mac.

The issue is this command has to have high enough priority that it runs before other processes run.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to run an instance of macOS inside a VM with kernel debugging on. Alternatively look into auditd, hopefully it starts soon enough.

Comment: I'd echo the use of the audit subsystem. [This](https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/quick-dirty-openbsm-auditing-macos/) is a decent crash course on the basics.

Comment: @Kentzo, your first solution would be time consuming - perhaps the file is being created by an application that is not a part of the OS? I will look into auditd.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to open terminal at login and have it run a command immediately?

Comment: Firstly consider what is meant by "file is not part of the OS". At the end it's some systemcall and thus traceble with kernel debugging. As of running a command immediately, I'd say forget about it before you dedicate your time learning the way of launchd. It's a path of sorrow.

Comment: @Kentzo, you suggest creating a VM with a duplicate of my HD or just installing a fresh copy of macOS on the VM? The file is most likely created by a non system application. I did take your suggestion of looking at auditd files. Problem is there are quite a few and they are in binary - not searchable without first using `praudit -x` and exporting to a searchable file.

Comment: I suggest a VM with minimal setup to reproduce the case. For auditd look up the SUpraudit tool.